# Search memo field using space-separated keywords?

Tags: sql, search

given the following test records

ID, MemoField

1, "apples oranges mangoes peaches"

2, "oranges bananas apples"

3, "oranges plums cherries"

4, "bananas cherries kiwi"

and having keywords entered in a single text field as: "apples oranges"

I want to be able to return records 1, 2 and 3 because those records either contain apples or oranges....

I want to assume that spaces in the list of keywords imply an OR.

How can I write a safe, parameterized query to make this happen?  I was thinking of taking the keywords, splitting them and generating clauses for each of the words and OR-ing them, but that doesn't seem efficient especially as the list of keywords get longer....

I'm really at a loss, please help.

Thanks,
Lou

Answer (score 0):

I found SQL Server Full-Text and the FREETEXT function.  Hopefully this works out.

Thanks,
M